# Retrieve remote JSON content with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have the problem of retrive a Json into my Jquery script.

A php script, located at http://myserver.com/script.php return  by echo a JSON like:

```
{"locations":[{"name":18492554,"lat":"12345","long":"234"},{"name":18492553,"lat":"4567","long":"234},{"name":18492555,"lat":"2234","long":"234}]}
```

I want to plot  that point into my Jqueru script like:

```
(function() {
    window.onload = function() {

        // Creating a new map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.6, -0.88),
          zoom: 12,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });


        ///////////////////// GET the JSON data   ///////////////////
var json =   // ???????



        // Creating a global infoWindow object that will be reused by all markers
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        // Looping through the JSON data
        for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {

                var data = json[i],
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long);

            // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
            //var iconBase = 'https://dea-srl.net/domenico/traking/js/';

            var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                title: data.nombre,
                icon: iconBase + 'schools_maps.png'
                });

            // Creating a closure to retain the correct data, notice how I pass the current data in the loop into the closure (marker, data)
            (function(marker, data) {

                // Attaching a click event to the current marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.nombre);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });


            })(marker, data);

        }

    }

})();
```

My problem is get that Json into de jquery. It is possible?

I tryed using get metho like:

```
$.get(" http://myserver.com/script.php");
```

but it doesnt works.

Any idea about that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work?"  What happens?  Do you get an error?

Comment: I do not Know how debug, but i try putting analert later, alert(json), and it is not showed. How can I get an error?

Comment: is http://myserver.com the same domain of your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean by doesn't work? What errors you have?

Are you using the `done` function?

```
$.get(" http://myserver.com/script.php").done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

or you can use directly the [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function.

Comment: the consolo of your piece of program puts: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

$.get(" http://myserver.com/script.php").done(function(data) {

Comment: adding library <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> resolve the error

Comment: my fault! although my problem was about the get method! thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON('http://myserver.com/script.php', function(data) {
  var json = data;
});
```

To load the json data.
If there is any other issue, you have be a bit more precise.